# Ошибка после преобразования py -> exe

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

Подскажите пожалуйста. Использую библиотеку pyautogui. OpenCv есть и в интерпретаторе все работает, но пре преобразовании с помощью pyinstaller вылезает ошибка:
NotImplementedError: The confidence keyword argument is only available if OpenCV is installed.

Уже все что можно  прогуглил, но решение нет( [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему переустановкой opencv-python, установил более старую версию и проблема решилась. Была последняя версия 4.6.0.66. Установил 4.5.5.64

Comment: дополните какая версия была и какая более старая